# cluster attributes using hclust in R

Tags: r, attributes, cluster-analysis, label, hclust

I have a data set which is two dimensional data with column names as attributes and rows as items. A sample is given below:

```
       A1    A2   A3   A4   ....
Item1  0     1     0    0
Item2  0     0     0    1
Item3  1    1      0    0
```

....

I have used hclust (ward.D2 method) to create a cluster dendrogram in R.  I can get the labels of all items in a cluster. How do i find out the list of attributes (A1 A2 etc) of the cluster so I can infer how those items came together?

The code which i have tried is :

```
d <- vegdist(data,method="jaccard")
fit <- hclust(d,method="ward.D2")
plot(fit)
hcd <- as.dendrogram(fit)
plot(cut(hcd,h=3)$upper)
labels(cut(hcd, h=3)$lower[[1]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hierarchical clustering does not handle columns.

It operates on the *distance matrix* - there are no column labels anymore.

You may be looking for biclustering instead.

Comment: Start with Cheng & Church.